# "Missing Template" error after submitting a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a very simple application that determines whether two words are anagrams, but I'm having a lot of trouble doing it on RoR. I'm currently stuck on this "Missing template" error. I have the following form, which is just two text fields for the words and two labels and a submit button:

```
<%= form_for :solver, url: solver_solve_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label "First word or sentence" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first %><br>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label "Second word or sentence" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :second %><br>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<%end%>
```

And in the routes.rb file I have:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  post 'solver/solve'

  root 'welcome#index'
```

The SolverController looks like this:

```
class SolverController < ApplicationController
    def create
        render plain: params[:solver].inspect
    end

    def solve
        wordone = params[:solver][:first]
        wordtwo = params[:solver][:second]
        wordone.chars.sort { |a, b| a.casecmp(b) } .join
        puts wordone
        wordtwo.chars.sort { |a, b| a.casecmp(b) } .join
        puts wordtwo
    end
end
```

However when I fill in the form and press submit I get a missing template error:

```
Missing template solver/solve, application/solve with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/mariana/Documents/RD-anagram/anagram/app/views"
```

Can anyone explain to me what's happening and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: please, write full path of your file with form.

Comment: `~/Documents/RD-anagram/anagram/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb` this is the full path of the file, is this what you wanted?

Comment: where do you think the output goes and from which context is the create method called

Comment: I don't really know, I tried adding the create method because I read that it would solve the missing template issue, but I didn't understand why. And by output you mean the `render plain: ... ` line? I think it will display the content of the array on the page as text, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a `post` method, the controller action should redirect to another action conventionally. Otherwise, it will look for a view in `app/views/solver/solve.html.erb`. If you have such a view, it will render it, otherwise, it will yell at you for not telling it what to render.

Comment: So I'm assuming I made a mistake by defining this method as post? I want it to return a boolean or maybe a string, so I can render a page that displays that information. Should it be a get method then?

Comment: Controller actions don't "return" values conventionally. Typically, for an html request, a GET request will perform some logic in the controller action and then render a view; a POST or PUT request will perform some action, write to the database, then redirect to a GET action, which will render a view. You CAN render a view from a post action, it's just not conventional.

Comment: If you're wanting a method that returns a value, it should be written on a model, or a module, not on a controller.

Answer (score 1):

You must create the `/app/views/solver/solve.html.erb` file and write in this file your form.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html - please, read this article:)